# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tJYt.png)

this is my code why I am facing this error my use state is also not null
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f55V.png)

Answer (score 0):

videos is not an array when you're calling it. You can do a type of check to check if it's an array or check if it's not null.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that the Videos component is not getting a video as props. So to overcome the situation you can use

```
videos?.map()
```

So basically just add a question mark

```
return (
        <>
           { videos && <Stack direction='row' ... >}
        </>
       )
```

Comment: it worked for me thank you sir, but i was followig an YouTube video the same code worked for him but not for me why? but now your suggestion worked fine for me